# Do I have a negative question record or am I misinterpreting this symbol?

Tags: discussion, questions, badges, badge-progress

From what I saw on meta SE, a positive question record is when a user's `(total questions - negative questions - deleted questions - closed questions) / total questions` is higher than 0.5, and after I calculated mine - 0.69 - I determined that I have a positive question record.  However, this popup has a gray X next to text that says *"need positive question record"*.  Does this mean that I actually *don't* have a positive question record, or am I misinterpreting the symbol?

I have 18 questions with a score greater than or equal to 0, 8 that are negative (mostly from the early days of the account), and 26 total.  I don't believe that any are deleted and none are closed.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The easy answer here is that you have deleted questions that don't appear in your list of recently deleted ones and they throw your count off? (Just trying to make sense of the calculation)

Comment: You have 36 questions; 10 are deleted (8 within 60 days of being posted, which is what counts), 2 are closed, 12 have a score of -1 or lower. So your score is (36 - 8 - 2 - 12) / 36 = 14 / 36 = 0.39

Comment: @MartijnPieters 10 are deleted?  Is it possible you could message them as well as the closed ones to me?  I'm just curious as to why either a mod or I deleted 10 posts

Comment: @Jodast: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54660266), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54375843), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53309211), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52864742), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52122166), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51433009), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51392154), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50765163), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50648764), [10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50534600). #2 and #4 are closed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters upon further investigation it also seems as if negative/closed/deleted answers count 3 times in the formula, is this true?

Comment: @Jodast yes. A question that is closed, has a negative score and is deleted counts against you 3 times.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is that only if a question has all three factors??

Comment: @Jodast: No. If a question is only closed and has a negative score, it is counted 2 times. Questions can count separately for all three negative factors, basically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From common sense, the "X" symbol and the phrase "*need* positive question record" mean that you *don't* have it.

Additional proof is:

[image]

[Others state that the formula is accurate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383018/do-i-have-a-negative-question-record-or-am-i-misinterpreting-this-symbol/383019#comment688931_383018), you are just miscalculating it due to not seeing your non-recent deleted posts in your profile.

Though as a rule, don't put too much faith into publications of such sensitive intricate details. SE staff reserves the right to change them without notice and add undocumented details to discourage gaming the system. Only the tag description is official info, and it doesn't specify how the score is calculated.

Comment: So then is *0.69* not a good score?

Comment: @Jodast It is likely you are miscalculating your score.

Comment: The formula is still accurate.